# Why can't I start my Docker service anymore?

Tags: docker

I run Docker daily for development. Yesterday, I tried to do a `docker build ...` and I got the following error

```
ERRO[0000] failed to dial gRPC: cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is 'docker daemon' running on this host?: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: no such file or directory
```

I have seen this error before. I've tried restarting the service but often times I just reboot and it works just fine. I don't know why the service occasionally turns off but that's not really my issue. A reboot did not fix this as it usually does.

After a bunch of searching I found a few commands for restarting the service. One of which I'd already tried because I was pretty sure that was how it worked. However I get:

```
$ sudo service docker start
Failed to start docker.service: Unit docker.service not found.
$ sudo systemctl start docker
Failed to start docker.service: Unit docker.service not found.
```

And just for good measure though I knew this wouldn't work since it's not installed as an init.d service...

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/docker start
sudo: /etc/init.d/docker: command not found
```

A bunch more searching on line mostly blamed this on the current user not being a member of the dcoker group. However, that's not going to explain failure to start the service. That would only explain inability to connect to a running service. But just to head that off right now...

```
$ groups
mmachenry adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare kvm docker
```

My active user is a member of docker. Like I said I build with docker daily and it just stopped working yesterday.

I did some more digging. Found nothing here:

```
$ ls /var/run/docker*
ls: cannot access '/var/run/docker*': No such file or directory
```

Anyone know why this might have stopped working? It seems like the daemon was uninstalled. I can't imagine how that could be. Also I'm a solo user on a privately owned laptop, so this isn't a machine with other users or anything.

```
$ uname -a
Linux mmachenry-laptop 4.15.0-1081-oem #91-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 1 02:03:58 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ docker --version
Docker version 19.03.8, build eb310fc
```

Anyone know what steps I might take to debug this?

Comment: switch to the `root` user and try, if it works then permissions is the problem.|

Comment: It's not, sadly.

Comment: I would re install docker and set the permissions again

Comment: hi, could you find the solution sir !

Comment: I ended up reinstalling my whole OS for unrelated reasons.